# A problem in the argument of Theorem 7.9 in M. Isaacs' CTFG

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, sylow-theory, characters

[image]

[image]

(Part of the book posted for reference) 
My question is about the paragraph in the bottom of the second image that the author claimed and proved that $\lambda^{N}\in \text{Irr}(N)$, but in my own calculation of its inner product in $\mathbb{C}[G]$( or say $\mathbb{C}[N]$) : $$[\lambda^{N},\lambda^{N}]_N=\frac{1}{|N|}\sum_{x\in N}\lambda^{N}(x)\overline{\lambda^{N}(x)}=\frac{1}{|N|}\sum_{x\in C}\frac{|N|^2}{|C|^2}\lambda(1)=\frac{|N|}{|C|}=2>1$$ where $C=C_{G}(P'), N=N_{G}(P')$ with $P'$ denoting the derived (commutator) subgroup of $P$;  $\lambda$ is a linear character of $C$ and $\lambda^N$ denoting the character induced to $N$.

Comment: How are you computing the induced character? What is $\lambda^N(x)$ precisely?

Comment: @David A.Craven As in the same book that  $\lambda^{N}(x)=\frac{1}{|C|}\sum_{z\in N,zxz^{-1}\in C}\lambda(zxz^{-1})$

Comment: OK, so how have you reduced $\lambda^N(x)\overline{\lambda^N(x)}$ to $\lambda(1)$? For example, if $x=1$ you obtain $\lambda^N(x)\overline{\lambda^N(x)}=4$.

Comment: @David A.Craven $zxz^{-1}\in C \Rightarrow \lambda(zxz^{-1})=\lambda(x)$ so that $\lambda^{N}(x)=\frac{|N|}{|C|}\lambda (x)$ and $\overline{\lambda(x)}=\lambda(x^{-1})$

Comment: Why is $\lambda(x^z)=\lambda(x)$? That's only true for elements that are conjugate in $C$. $z$ doesn't lie in $C$ in general, so this isn't true.

Comment: @ David A. Craven   Thanks for your clarification !!